# How can I use htaccess to solve domain.com/domain.com/URI from loading?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem with Codeigniter where it's processing

domain.com/domain.com/URI

Without generating a 404 error. Basically it's just loading domain.com/URI without chaning the url. So, I've got a potential duplicate content problem on my hands.

Rather than trying to hack the core, I'd like to change the htaccess to redirect

```
domain.com/http://domain.com/URI
```

to simply

domain.com/URI

I've tried googling solutions but none of them seem to be triggering the rewrite condition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+http://[^/]+(/[^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```